# Find the number of elements in $A \cup B \cup C$ if there are 50 elements in $A$, 500 in $B$, and 5,000 in $C$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I am given this:

Find the number of elements in $A \cup B \cup C$ if there are 50 elements in $A$, 500 in $B$, and 5,000 in $C$ if:

1. $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$
2. The sets are pairwise disjoint.
3. There are two elements common to each pair of sets and one element in all
   three sets

For #1, would the answer simply be $A \cap B$ and $B \cap C$, given that if A is a subset of B, and B is a subset of C, then A and B having common elements (as well as B and C), then it would be the union of the two sets?

As for the other two, I am a little confused by the wording and could use some help on those.

Comment: I'll add them now.

Comment: "For #1, would the answer simply be $A \cap B$ and $B \cap C$" Sorry but how can the answer to the question "Find the number of elements in $A \cup B \cup C$" be "$A \cap B$ and $B \cap C$"? One is asked for a *number*, no?

Comment: condition 1 contradicts to condition 2. Otherwise, you should use Venn diagram to solve this type of problems.

Comment: I see your point there. This question is very confusing to me, so bear with me. @Did

Comment: I'll try to use the Venn Diagram. @runaround

Comment: #1: What do the two conditions imply w.r.t. to the relationship between $A$ and $C$? Then you have an immediate answer. #2: Straighforward, I would say. #3: Similar to #2, you only have to subtract common elements in a proper way. Here I would assume that the two elements common to a pair of sets are not(!) a member of the third set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pairwise disjoint" means that the number of elements in $A \cup B \cup C$ equals the sum of the number of elements in $A,$ $B,$ and $C$ counted distincly. This is simply $5000 + 500 + 50 = \boxed{5550}.$

Use PIE on the last part. We find the answer as follows:
$$(5000 + 500 + 50) - (2 + 2 + 2) + 1$$
$$= \boxed{5545}.$$

Answer (score 1):

1. If $A\subseteq B \subseteq C$, then $A\cup B\cup C = C$.
2. In general, $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|B\cap C| -|C\cap A|+|A\cap B\cap C|$. If sets are pairwise disjoint, what will happen? And how about third question?

Answer (score 0):

I remember this question... here is an excerpt from my old textbook.
Note that the threes in the last line would simply be twos because your question differed in what it was asking by just that.

[image]